# How we can show loader during asynchronous call in phonegap

Tags: ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile, asynchronous

I am trying to show the loader during asynchronous call, but loader is not display. 
This is what i have done so far.

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : 'http://demo.co.in/projects/demo/webservice/',
        dataType : "json", 
        async : false, 
        beforeSend: function(){
                      $('#pageLoader').show( "slow", function() { }); 
                      $('#pageLoader').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" />');     
                    },
        success : function(data) {   
        }, 
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Server timed out. Please try again.") 
        }  
    });
```

One thing i have notice so far, when i remove the async : false, from my code after that loader is display.

Comment: async option set to false is synchronous. delete that if you want  asynchronous -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re -- i would delete the beforeSend: function(){ and put your loader above $.ajax({

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single threading, you should use the async mode and make your code event driven.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
async : true,
```

by doing that you'll declare ajax call as asynchronous